# Setting relative pythonpath for project in Windows (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to set up an environment for Python project to help out a friend (developing on different OS).
I want to set environment variables per project in the .env file, but ultimately it fails to recognize Pythonpath.

The goal is to set the /api subfolder of my currently opened folder, but ir doesn't recognize the relative path. Writing there absolute path (as in screenshot below) sort of works - it recognizes the custom library and all others, but on debugging it fails on other relative paths in the code (or so it appears)

[image: Here is screenshot from my .env file - relative and absolute path I'm attempting to set]

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: According to [VS Code Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_variable-substitution), this should work only if you have `PROJ_DIR` variable defined in the `.env` file as well. On the other hand, it does not work for me even in that case.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to avoid the whole environment setup to begin with and define your dependencies in source. This works when your repo has all you need.

Consider the project structure like this

```
proj
   /api
       api_source.py
   /utils
       utils_source.py
   /tests
```

api_source.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../')))
import utils.utils_source as utils_source
```

It's a bit messy but I like this approach in that I do not have to setup any environment wherever I clone my repo, at least not for the self contained dependencies within the repo itself.

Usually I'll do this path appending in the Main script and structure all my imports in the dependencies to rely on a fixed path prefix in the path list that way I do this operation once and all the dependent modules run with it.